# Android startActivityforResult from java which does NOT extend Activity

Tags: android, bluetooth, library-project

For a Bluetooth library I want to call a `startActivityForResult` to enable Bluetooth. I want to do this in my own library project. The problem is that `sartActivityForResult` only works for Activities, my library is not an activity, of course my project using  this library project is having an activity. I tried two things

1.
Had my library to extend Activity, so I am creating the object like a normal `POJO`. Hence when calling startActivityForResult it throws a null pointer.

2.
Tried to get my Activity to pass it into the constructor of my library object. I am not able to to get an activity object, only context but that doesn't help.

What can I do?

EDIT: Some Code

I have the following class in my library project:

```
public class mylib
{

public mylib()
{
    // Do some bluetooth setup thing here
    // figure out that bluetooth is not enabled so try to enable it now
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); 
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
 }

onActivityResult()
{
    // Report back that BT is enabled now
}
}
```

Then I have of course my Android application using this library project in onCreate() I do something like this

```
  public class Myactivity() extends Activity
  {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
     // do all the normal stuff 

  mylib pojo = new mylib(); // This creates a POJO which needs to startActivityForResults(...), see above code
   }
   }
```

The two options I mentioned above

1. I don't see how I can convince mylib to call startActivityForResult doing

   ```
     public class mylib extends Activity
   ```

doesn't seem to do the trick.

1. I could overload my constructor of mylib to pass in the activity object, I have no idea how to create the activity object.

Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: may be below thing will help you in this matter http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: Can you upload code of your Java class ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. What will instigate the call to `startActivityForResult(...)`? You'll actually need a real `Activity` to receive the result.

Comment: @Squonk That is exactly the issue. See the code snippet above. The bluetooth step to enable BT is what I want to have reusable in my library which is not an activity.

Comment: @AndyAndroid : To explain further about what I was asking. There should already be an `Activity` or some way a user can interact before you try to do this. For example, there's a reason why a `Service` can't directly start an `Activity` - it would be really bad practice if a UI suddenly appeared without a user knowing it was going to happen. A `Service` can, however, start an `Activity` indirectly though a `PendingIntent` and a `Notification`. My point is basically you have to have an `Activity` to start with in order to call `startActivityForResult(..)` in order to obtain a result.

Comment: of course I have an activity, that activity is using the library. The point is that I want to put all BT setup things into the lib, the lib is of course not an activity and thus I have trouble calling startActivityForResult(...)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a constructor of your java class which has parameter of type Activity like below,

```
public class MyClass 
{
      private Activity activity;
      public MyClass ( Activity activity ) 
      {
          this.activity = activity;
      }
}
```

Now you can use this `activity` variable to call startAcvitiyForResult from your Java class.

Comment: how would I create the activity object in my android project to pass it into the constructor?